# потоки ввода-вывода

Tags: php

https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php

> php://stdin, php://stdout и php://stderr позволяют получить прямой
>   доступ к соответствующим потокам ввода или вывода процесса PHP. Поток
>   php://stdin предназначен только для чтения, тогда как php://stdout и
>   php://stderr предназначены только для записи.

Где и как на практике эти потоки применяют? Эта теория мне ничего не прояснила. Это в консоли можно настроить вывод и правку команд для оформления?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, да - это в консоли, во-первых это по сути даёт доступ к операционной системе из php-приложения, во-вторых - перенаправления потоков ( к примеру в файл, или на другую консоль (через ssh-туннель)) полезны при проектировании более сложных  и интересных проектов. Мною применяется при рефакторинге и оптимизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любые данные, которые поступают от вебсервера к php передаются через поток ввода STDIN. К примеру данные в формате POST, GET неявно сериализуются и преобразуются в суперглобальные массивы. Но если вам понадобится прочитать данные в формате PUT , вам придется проделать тоже самое вручную:

```
$put = array();
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put);
```

Answer (score 3):

Например, при написании [CLI-скриптов](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.usage.php) для ввода-вывода.
Абстрактный код:

```
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
$stderr = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');

fwrite($stdout, 'Выполняем действие: ...');

$result = someAction($params);

if ($result === false) {
    fwrite($stderr, 'При выполнении действия произошла ошибка: ...');
}
```

При запуске содержащего этот код скрипта из консоли сообщения будут выведены в соответствующие [стандартные потоки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).